# How to listen fcm notification in flutter when app is killed and show an alert regarding the notification?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, background, alert

I am trying to build a true caller like app, so I need to show the alert. I tried using system_alert_window package. That is working fine, now only one issue is the alert should be shown only when the app is in killed state. For that I have to listen the incoming notifications when the app is killed, is there any way for that.